# Remove deleted javascript from body

Tags: javascript, magento-1.6

I deleted the file in my **ftp** but it is still being loaded on every page at the end of the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookieinfo"
    src="/media/js/cookieinfo.min.js">
</script>
```

Would the method to removing it be placing this text in the `page.xml` file?

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><script>media/js/cookieinfo.min.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want delete that js file from entire page in your website, try to place this code in your local.xml, if the local.xml file still does not exist you can create it in the this folder :

```
<project_root>/app/design/frontend/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml
```

and then write this code in your local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout>
   <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
          <type>js</type>
          <name>media/js/cookieinfo.min.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

you can reference to this link for detail answer :

[Js file is not removed from xml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55066/js-file-is-not-removed-from-xml#answer-55068)

Answer (score 1):

1. If your js file is in : `root/js/`, use this:

   ```
   <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>file.js</name></action>
   ```
2. If your js file is in : `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/`, use this :

   ```
   <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>file.js</name></action>
   ```
3. Clean cache, then it should work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I phrased the question incorrectly. Still new at Magento. My solution was that I had forgotten the script was still in the System>Configuration>Design>Footer in the Miscellaneous HTML block. That's what was generating a 404.